# Matlab is rounding my sigmoid function

Tags: matlab, logistic-regression

I have implemented a sigmoid function as follows in Matlab.

```
function [y] = sig(x)
    y = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
end
```

When I give it a large input such as 100, the function rounds off my result and gives me a 1.

How can I get its accurate value? Is it possible or am I limited to a low range for the value of x.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the difference between 1 and your sigmoid function, you could define a function with the simplified mathematical expression:

1 - 1/(1+exp(-x)) = (1+exp(-x))/(1+exp(-x)) - 1/(1+exp(-x)) = exp(-x) / (1+exp(-x))

```
function [y] = one_minus_sig(x)
    y = exp(-x) / (1+exp(-x));
end
```

And then:

```
one_minus_sig(100) = 3.7200759760208356e-44
```

Answer (score 0):

1.0000000000000... is accurate to about 44 digits so I'm not sure what the problem would be?

Edit: In an earlier version, I said 300 digits - for some reason I had used x=900 in that computation.  Here are a few digits:

0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999996279924023979164037040304196136881662641107846012870706553139188204855222012652822147634307

Computed using Maple.

Comment: From my understanding, the sigmoid function goes towards 1 at infinity. Despite 100 being a respectively large input, the sigmoid should return a number very close to 1, but should not be equal to 1. I wish to get that number.

Comment: How do you want that number defined though? To a fixed number of digits?  If so, use something like Maple.  Exactly? In which case, you will probably have to work with an algebraic form.  The post by y300 is also useful.